# How can a Regex match everything after group 1 unless group 1 pattern appears again on the same line?

Tags: regex, regex-group

I'm having an issue understanding how I can capture everything after an optional prefix, unless, that prefix is displayed again. It would be nice to have the [FFFFFF] tag get matched a start over as group 1 vs being an optional additional group.

I'm new-ish to regex and I love the regex101.com site but this just appears to be above my level of understanding.

Expression:

```
(\[[0-9a-fA-F]{6}\])?(.*)
```

Sample Text

```
[00B800][!] Green - [004DB8] Blue does not match!!

[FFFFff][!] White

[e60000][!] Red

123456

Test string, another test abcdef
```

This is the result I'm attempting to get.

[image]

Link

https://regex101.com/r/z3CbHm/2/

Comment: Do you mean like this? `^(\[[0-9a-fA-F]{6}\])(?!.*\[[0-9a-fA-F]{6}\])(.+)`  https://regex101.com/r/m2T0OD/1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use 2 capturing group, making the first group optional.

Then for the second group, match either until you see the next occurrence of the pattern `\[[0-9a-fA-F]{6}\]` or the end of the string.

```
(\[[0-9a-fA-F]{6}\])?(.+?)(?=\[[0-9a-fA-F]{6}\]|$)
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/BzRSOI/1)

If you want to omit possible leading whitespace chars for the second group:

```
(\[[0-9a-fA-F]{6}\])?(?:[^\S\r\n]*(.+?))(?=\[[0-9a-fA-F]{6}\]|$)
```

That will match

- `(\[[0-9a-fA-F]{6}\])?` Match the pattern in optional **group 1**
- `(?:` Non capture group

  - `[^\S\r\n]*` Match 0+ occurrences of a whitespace char except a newline
  - `(.+?)`Capture **group 2**, match 1+ occurrences of any char except a newline
- `)` Close group
- `(?=` Positive lookhead, assert what is on the right is

  - `\[[0-9a-fA-F]{6}\]` Match the pattern
  - `|` Or
  - `$` End of string
- `)` Close lookahead

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/WJ61XB/1)

Comment: I don't believe I clearly stated my desired outcome, I've updated the question with some details about the information I'm attempting to capture. Thank you for taking the time!

Comment: @Landmine Do you mean like this? `(\[[0-9a-fA-F]{6}\])?(.+?)(?=\[[0-9a-fA-F]{6}\]|$)` https://regex101.com/r/BzRSOI/1

Comment: you beautiful human! Thank you! And such a well explained answer! I wish I could up vote you more than once.

Comment: @Landmine You are welcome, glad it works for you :-) Good luck!